# Why does the integer key of a php array become negative (< 0)?

Tags: php, array-filter

```
var_dump(array_filter(array(4294967295 => 22)));
```

The result:

```
array(1) {  
    [-1] =>  
    int(22)
}
```

Why the key is < 0 ?

Comment: Because you're trying to set an integer key > PHP_INT_MAX

Comment: For info, PHP_INT_MAX  is 2 147 483 647 (your value being 4 294 967 295 )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Max size of `int`are as follows:-

**32-bit builds of PHP:**

```
Integers can be from -2147483648 to 2147483647
```

**64-bit builds of PHP:**

```
Integers can be from -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807
```

It seems you are using 32 bit builds and that's why you are getting that problem.

Answer (score 6):

This is because of [**Arithmetic overflow**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_overflow). Since biggest integer number in PHP is `PHP_INT_MAX`, which is only `2147483647` (32-bit).

So the "so-called" number `2147483648` is overflowed then will come `-2147483648`, `2147483649` becomes `-2147483647` and so on...

**Your number `4294967295` finally ends up at -1.**

This whole things happens because in computer science, we use [**Two's Complement**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) to represents smaller than 0 numbers. This does not make sense in real life, but for computer, **Two's complement** is much more easier and faster to compute.

For your problem, you can change your PHP to 64-bits version. Or getting around it by not using the number which is > PHP_INT_MAX in this case.

Comment: 2147483647 is 2^31-1, which is the maximum 32-bit int value, not 64

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: thanh kiu :v. The first version I stated the correct number but after editing, I mistakenly put the wrong number there.